# What's callback in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm learning kotlin in intelij Idea, and I have to make presentation about interfaces. One subject is callback, where can I find information about it? or can you tell me simply, veery simply, what's call back?

```
fun main() {
val myphone = Myphone()
myphone.phoneOn()
myphone.onClick()
myphone.onTouch()
myphone.openApp()
myphone.closeApp()
}

interface Application {
    var AppName: String

    fun openApp()

    fun closeApp() {
        println("$AppName App is closed!")
    }
}

interface Button {
    var helloMessage: String

    fun phoneOn()

    fun onClick()

    fun onTouch() {
        println("The screen was touched!")
    }
}


class Myphone: Button, Application {
    override var AppName: String = "Facebook"

    override fun openApp() {
        println("$AppName Is Open!")
    }
    override var helloMessage: String = "Hello"

    override fun onClick() {
        println("The screen was clicked!")
    }

    override fun phoneOn() {
        println("$helloMessage !")
    }
 }
```

Comment: Well, this question actually does not need any code to be provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VERY simply: callback means the function, that is executed on the other function's finish or some specific event happening.

```
fun execute() {
    // Some logic 
    executeAnotherOnFinish();
}
```

OR

```
// filter executes only after array converted to list
myIntArray.toList().filter { it > 0 }
```

OR

```
myListener.notify()

// Listener class methid
notify() {
    // Do some work
    executeCallback()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That will help me!

Answer (score 0):

Callback is not just Kotlin related, its very common programming technique which is primarily used with asynchronous programming. The simplest explanation is that it is function that will be called back (hence the name) once some asynchronous event has occurred.

Button's onClick function is quite good example of that, we have some logic that we need to execute but we want it to run only when button is clicked so we provide callback which will be called once that button is clicked.

Comment: Such a good answer! Thanks <3 I can't understand why my question has 2 downvotes btw.

Comment: SO has a bit higher standard for asking questions, meaning one should first do his research and only then ask question. So questions like this which are quite common are frequently downvoted.

Comment: I couldn't find good answer, Stackoverflow is always my last choice.

Comment: Where did you look?  Even Wikipedia has a [good description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))!

Comment: @ლაშანუროშვილი if Steyrix's or mine answer helped you please mark it as accepted answer so the question is closed.